# returning a value from void function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I have some block of code which designated to get a number from the main program and convert it to `char *`
The problem start when I want to print it in the main program and not in the function.

This is what i tried so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void help(int number, char* result);
int main()
{
    char arr[100] = "";
    int number;
    printf("enter number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    help(number, &arr);
    printf("number is %d and string is %s\n", number, &arr);
    return 0;
}

void help(int number, char* result)
{
    *result = number;
}
```

The outcome result:

> number is 15 and string is

I tried many different ways and variations and still no luck. suggestions?

Comment: creating a global variable?

Comment: Allowed to use only pointers, since its a h.w based on pointers

Comment: What do you expect to happen when number > 255?

Comment: i tried with sprintf and got an violtion error: "sprintf_s(arr, "%d", number);"

Comment: *since its a h.w based on pointers*  If this really were on hardware based on pointers, it wouldn't have `scanf_s()`, which is effectively and non-portably implemented only on Windows by Microsoft.  Hint:  don't use `scanf_s()` no matter how MSVC whines because it's lying to you.

Answer (score 1):

`arr` already points to the address of the first element of the array, so you should remove the ampersand before it.

In your function you're actually assigning `number` to the first char of the array. That is the same as writing `arr[0] = number;`. If `number` has the value 65 for example, your code will print an uppercase A, since it is the corresponding character in the ASCII table.

What you want to do instead is to write the number to the string. You can do it with the function `sprintf` from `<stdio.h>`:

```
void help(int number, char *result) {
    sprintf(result, "%d", number);
}
```

The first argument is the string you're "printing" onto, the second specifies what you're actually writing and the syntax is that of the normal `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the help function as:
`*result = number;` -> `sprintf(result, "%d", number);`

Answer (score 0):

assigning "*result = number;" will set first character in character array (arr[0]) to value present in number, array[0] can hold a max value of 256 (-128to128).
"*result = number;" this will not convert a number to a character array or string.

to create a character array or string snprintf is usefule.

```
    int a = 12;
    char arr[128] = {0};
    snprintf(arr, 128, "%d", a);
    printf("%s \n", arr);
```

function can be modified to include this.

```
    void help(int number, char* result, int result_size)
    {
          snprintf(result, result_size, "%d", number);
    }
```